# Is this Recursion computing the powers of 2 from 1 to n us correct?

Tags: java

First call of int prev = powersOf2(n / 2) should got to else block where it
will be shown as 50 but compiler showing below

Is this Recursion computing the powers of 2 from 1 through n correct?

```
package Example_16;

public class Example {

 public static int powersOf2(int n) {
     if (n < 1) {
            return 0;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(1);
            return 1;
       } else {
         int prev = powersOf2(n / 2);
         int curr = prev * 2;
         System.out.println(curr);
         return curr;
    }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    powersOf2(50);
     }

}
```

First call of int prev = powersOf2(n / 2) should got to else block where it
will be shown as 50 but compiler showing below

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
```

But output is printed as ,but how its returning 8 16 and 32

```
print & return 1
print & return 2
print & return 4
print & return 8
print & return 16
print & return 32
```

Comment: If you step through this with your debugger, you'll see very quickly what you've done wrong.

Comment: 2^n != 2 * 2^(n/2)

Comment: It loos like your algo will always return the biggest power of 2 that is less or equal the input (for non-negative input, 0 else).